# Heap corruption using strcat

Tags: c++

One of my weaknesses is effectively using chars in C++ which is what I am trying to do right now. I have a player class in my game and within the player class, I create a playerCard object which displays various information. This works fine for a single instance of the player object (i.e. Player player) but when I attempt to push_back a player object in to a vector it all goes wrong.

Basically, the program continues to run but the player doesn't render to the screen. When I quit the program, I then get a breakpoint error when main tries to return MSG. The comment about the breakpoint reads:

```
    /*
     * If this ASSERT fails, a bad pointer has been passed in. It may be
     * totally bogus, or it may have been allocated from another heap.
     * The pointer MUST come from the 'local' heap.
     */
    _ASSERTE(_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData));
```

I have located the error to here

```
    strcat(nameCard, nameChar);
    strcat(nameCard, genderChar);
    strcat(nameCard, ageChar);
    strcat(nameCard, cashHeldChar);
    strcat(nameCard, productWantedChar);
```

within the playerCard class because when I comment this out, I do not get the error. Here is the full playerCard class (Again, it is messy and probably the wrong way for going about things but I am trying to get my head round using chars/strings etc)
    #include "Headers.h";

```
class Playercard{

private:

    RECT textbox;
    LPD3DXFONT font;

    std::string nameStr;
    std::string genderStr;
    std::string ageStr;
    std::string cashHeldStr;
    std::string prodWantedStr;

    char nameCard[1000];

public:

    Playercard()
    {
    }

    void load(char* name, bool male, int age, double cash, char* prod)
    {

        if(male)
        {
            genderStr = "Gender: Male\n";
        }
        else
        {
            genderStr = "Gender: Female\n";
        }

        nameStr = "Name: " + static_cast<std::ostringstream*>( &(std::ostringstream() << name))->str() + "\n";
        ageStr = "Age: " + static_cast<std::ostringstream*>( &(std::ostringstream() << age))->str() + "\n";
        cashHeldStr = "Cash Held: " + static_cast<std::ostringstream*>( &(std::ostringstream() << cash))->str() + "\n";
        prodWantedStr = "Product Wanted: " + static_cast<std::ostringstream*>( &(std::ostringstream() << prod))->str() + "\n";

        char * nameChar = new char [nameStr.length()+1];
        char * genderChar = new char [genderStr.length()+1];
        char * ageChar = new char [ageStr.length()+1];
        char * cashHeldChar = new char [cashHeldStr.length()+1];
        char * productWantedChar = new char [prodWantedStr.length()+1];

        strcpy(nameChar, nameStr.c_str());
        strcpy(genderChar, genderStr.c_str());
        strcpy(ageChar, ageStr.c_str());
        strcpy(cashHeldChar, cashHeldStr.c_str());
        strcpy(productWantedChar, prodWantedStr.c_str());

        strcat(nameCard, nameChar);
        strcat(nameCard, genderChar);
        strcat(nameCard, ageChar);
        strcat(nameCard, cashHeldChar);
        strcat(nameCard, productWantedChar);

        diagFile.open("Diag.txt");
        diagFile.write("Test", 100);
        diagFile.close();
    }

    void setUp(int L, int T, int R, int B)
    {
        SetRect(&textbox, L,T,R,B);
    }

    void draw()
    {
        font->DrawTextA(d3dSprite, nameCard, -1, &textbox, DT_LEFT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
    }

    LPCSTR plCard()
    {
        return nameCard;
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you're using character arrays and pointers instead of concatenating the C++ strings and then using `c_str()`? Also, just use `nameStr = std::string("Name: ") + name + "\n";`, or better yet, take a string as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I will change to using this. As I mentioned... not brilliant with strings :/

Comment: You don't need all those `ostringstream`s. To build, for example, `nameStr`, you can either do `nameStr = "Name: "; nameStr += name;` or `nameSTr = std::string("Name: ") + name;`. Or you can not do it at all, and only generate that stuff when you need it.

Comment: This is actually a good question compared to what usually comes around. The title describes the problem, the problem is narrowed down correctly to a very limited scope, all of the code we needed to see was provided, and not much more, and, although it may not be the first thing noticeable, the OP is not unnecessarily stubborn when the answer they're actually looking for is given.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that as far as the code provided goes, `font` is uninitialized before dereferencing it in `draw()`. You'll want to make sure it's properly initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that `nameCard` is uninitialized. `strcat` requires a null-terminated string to do its magic, and there's no guarantee that the first, or any, character in `nameCard` is a null.

However, C strings are unnecessary. Just use `std::string` all the time. After changing `nameCard` to a string, I'd change `load` to (file writing excluded):

```
void load(const std::string &name, bool male, int age, double cash, const std::string &prod)
{
    nameStr = "Name: " + name + "\n";
    genderStr = "Gender: " + (male ? "Male" : "Female") + "\n";
    ageStr = "Age: " + std::to_string(age) + "\n";
    cashHeldStr = "Cash Held: " + std::to_string(cash) + "\n";
    prodWantedStr = "Product Wanted: " + prod + "\n";

    nameCard = nameStr + genderStr + ageStr + cashHeldStr + prodWantedStr;
}
```

I would actually just make `nameCard` a data member, removing the others, and use this:

```
nameCard.clear();
nameCard += "Name: " + name + "\n";
//add on other parts
```

Other than that, make `plCard()` return a `std::string` and in `draw()`, use `nameCard.c_str()`. I hope that clears up what you can do with strings a bit more.

Do note, however, that `std::to_string` is C++11. C++03 has two common solutions:

```
std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(someNumber);
```

Or

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << someNumber;
std::string str = oss.str();
```

I find the three-liner much more readable than a one-liner or two-liner.

Answer (score 3):

Your `nameCard` is uninitialized. Replace the first `strcat` with `strcpy`, or initialize it with a zero string.

Now, how about using `std::string` exclusively?

Comment: Thank you very very much! Worked :) Yes, I am very aware that this requires some work which I shall now start on! Thanks for the help